# Cannot set breakpoints with GDB and OpenOCD for STM32F4 with ST-Link

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, stm32, openocd

I'm trying to use OpenOCD with GDB to debug the STM32F4 Cortex-M4 on my STM32F4Discovery board.

Setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- OpenOCD 0.9.0 (also tested with 0.10-dev)
- arm-none-eabi-gdb 7.10
- STM32F4Discovery with ST-Link v2 (V2J28S0)
- Project code generated with STM32CubeMX

I made sure debug wire is enabled in STM32CubeMX (this keeps the debug wire pins in default state)

GCC flags are:

```
-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g -fno-common -fmessage-length=0
```

I added simple blinking LED code to the main loop, to test the debugging.

I start OpenOCD with `openocd -f board/stm32f4discovery.cfg -c "program build/discovery_simple_test.elf verify reset"`. OpenOCD flashes the chip and resets it. (Output of OpenOCD can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/iamniels/3b1d092d2b651f390b53383ecdb5d37f))

Now I connect to it with GDB:

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:3333
Remote debugging using localhost:3333
0x08001450 in ?? ()
(gdb) set verbose on
(gdb) file "/abs_path/build/discovery_simple_test.elf"
A program is being debugged already.
Are you sure you want to change the file? (y or n) y
Load new symbol table from "/abs_path/build/discovery_simple_test.elf"? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from /abs_path/build/discovery_simple_test.elf...done.
Reading in symbols for /abs_path/Src/main.c...done.
(gdb) monitor reset
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8000232: file /abs_path/Src/main.c, line 71.
(gdb) break /abs_path/Src/main.c:93
Breakpoint 2 at 0x8000258: file /abs_path/Src/main.c, line 93.
```

The program should break at line 93, but it doesn't.

When I halt the execution and try to continue it, it doesn't continue:

```
(gdb) monitor halt
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x21000000 pc: 0x080006d8 msp: 0x2001ffe8
(gdb) monitor continue
//Program doesn't continue
```

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you know for sure that you hit main function?
Do you have the correct clock settings?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Clock settings were the default settings from STM32CubeMX. I have updated the on-board ST-Link to a J-Link adapter and I'm now using Segger's GDB server. Now I at least can continue with my project.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue i add the following command  in openocd :
-c gdb_breakpoint_override hard

Answer (score 0):

May be another GDB-Instance is Running ?
"A program is being debugged already."
Look for a "arm-none-eabi-gdb" Process and kill it.

Comment: OpenOCD accepts only one GDB instance. I think "A program is being debugged already" is about the target's state. I have updated the on-board ST-Link to a J-Link adapter and I'm now using Segger's GDB server.

Comment: @i.amniels is correct, the debugger just detects that the micro is not sat in a reset state but is ticking away doing _something_

Answer (score 0):

I guess the command to use is just `continue` and not `monitor continue` since you have to tell GDB that the underlying software is running.

`monitor continue` tells the embedded system to continue but GDB does not know about it (it does not interpret the meaning of the `monitor` command, openocd does).